# What is \0 in a string?

Tags: string, escaping

I am aware of string escapements which can be used to insert special characters, for example there is the \u---- escapement, where - is a hexadecimal digit, which can be used to insert any utf-16 character. <strike>I mean can be used to insert any character with its utf-16 code. Except emoji which take up two "characters" which arent really characters because the emojis are actually just utf-32 characters. Except the emojis which are a pictograph followed by U+FE0F. Anyways,</strike> what is the function of \0 in a string?

I have tried searching on google and stackoverflow and even w3school's javascript String lesson and could not find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the escape sequence for the null character. More details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: Interesting so it does the same thing as \u0000 right? If so, it sometimes glitches into the beginning of the text when I use this https://jsfiddle.net/cmarangu/qucws6gq/